# How to create an android app that presses a button on a website whenever I open the app

Tags: android

I have a website that will not change. I wish to be able to open an app and have it press a specific button on the website. The main reason for this is that the website is designed to be accessed for about 2 seconds, type your name, hit the button and leave.

Just curious is anyone has any ideas.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse-engineer the website to see what does the button do, then in `onCreate` of your launcher Activity, post a request (mostly a `POST` request) to fake the action of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent filter in your manifest file. He is an example code.

```
<activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- for link -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="test.com"
                android:path="users/test"
                android:pathPrefix="/"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```